# Solspace Supersearch Breaking with Dash in Title

Tags: solspace, supersearch

When using Solspace SuperSearch I've noticed that the search will stop searching at a dash (-) in the title or any other field. For example, if I was searching for "Bar" the entry "Foo Bar" would be returned, but "Foo - Bar" would not. Is there a way to fix this without having to rewrite all the titles?

Comment: What version of Super Search are you using?
What version of EE are you using? Can you show your search and result template code?

Comment: I'm having the same issue I have categories with dashes in Admin - Secretarial for example it returns no results. I'm assuming - is being treated as a negative symbol as described here http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/results/#category Is there any workaround for this